# Spring Boot kafkaTemplate consumer message load and processing message

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

in my application I am using `Spring Boot kafkaTemplate` for consuming the messages. I am new to kafka with Spring Boot. I have added a consumer as below -

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${app.kafka.consumer.topic}'.split(',')}")
 public void receivedMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr, @Payload String message){
    log.info("Message received from topic {} ", cr.topic());
    //TODO
}
```

On a `topic` we will receive near about 200K messages per second. Ones I received `message` will send to another method for processing which filtered the messages based on certain criteria and then publishing the filtered `message` to another `topic`.

My question is, does above `@KafkaListener` method will handle this load or do I need to do any special treatment like `threading` or `concurrency`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on your workload, the number of cores in your CPU, etc, etc. In general, increasing the concurrency will provide more throughput (as long as you have at least that many partitions on the topic).

But, your downstream code must be completely thread-safe.

Even then, there may be other bottlenecks in your code (DB etc).

If all you are doing is computation, transformation, and publishing to another topic, without doing any other I/O, increasing the concurrency should definitely help.

The only real solution is experimentation and, if you don't get the throughput you need, profile your application.

You can't learn such skills without actually doing it.

Comment: Hi @Gary, thank you for your response. We decided to poll batch of the messages from kafka topic for that I am using `nack()` in case any exception but we are using `Spring Boot 2.1.8` and looks like `nack()` is not supported in 2.1.8 version. Can you please let me know equivalent `nack()` feature in `Spring Boot 2.1.8`

Comment: Don't ask unrelated questions in comments; it doesn't help people find questions/answers. Spring Boot 2.1.x has been end of life for nearly a year; `nack()` was introduced in spring-kafka 2.3.x (comes with Boot 2.2.x, which is also end-of-life). See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions As you can see, Boot 2.3.x goes end of life soon, too. There is no equivalent of `nack()` in earlier versions. See the project page for a matrix of spring-kafka/spring-boot versions. https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#overview